# IIS URL Rewrite rule - test works but no results

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module, iis-8.5

I’m having trouble writing a URL Rewrite rule for IIS 8.5. My expertise writing rules is barely intermediate, and the documentation has not been helpful.

I’m trying to redirect the following URL:

hostname.com/sub1/sub2/sub3/sub4

to this URL:

hostname.com/sub1/sub6/sub7/sub2/sub4

And by that, I mean —

- hostname.com is a variable. There are multiple hostnames served by this single .NET application.
- sub1 stays the same and is not a variable.
- sub2 is the sub that should trigger the pattern and is not
  a variable, however it gets moved to a different place in the URL.
- Given the previous two points, I assume the string ‘sub1/sub2’
  should be hardcoded into the pattern to identify the URLs to
  transform and to avoid redirect loops.
- sub3 gets deleted.
- sub4 is a variable.
- sub6 and sub7 are not variables.

I know I'm using the term variable incorrectly - what I mean by variable is that those parts of the URL change and need to be captured and used as back references.

Let me clarify with an example:

https://hostname.com/application/catalog/v3g5h6j8k9/feline-footwear

to ->

https://hostname.com/application/showcase/default/catalog/feline-footwear

All my attempts at writing a rule failed. I’m sure I’m doing everything wrong.

I thought I got close with this. The pattern tests all succeeded, but it would not pick up the incoming URL. I just get a 404:

```
            <rule name=“Catalog redir” enabled=“true” stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=“^(.*)/application/catalog/(.*)/(.*)” />
                <action type="Redirect" url=“{R:1}/application/showcase/default/catalog/{R:3}” redirectType="SeeOther" />
            </rule>
```

I’ve also tried using ([a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+) instead of (.*)

Also, I have this rule installed at the /application level of the tree, not the root. Could this be incorrect? Or better posed, how does the location of the rule in the web site tree correlate to the pattern? I couldn't find that in the docs either.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Placement of the rule within the tree, in regards to its format, was the issue. Since it was not placed in the root, but was placed in /application, once I got rid of the first section, so that the beginning of the match url was application, it started working.

Comment: can you please share what you used ?